# Whether a file uploaded is in tab-delimited format

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-upload

I am using ASP.Net fileupload control to allow users to upload a tab-delimited file with a txt extension.

**How would I make sure in code  that the file is tab-delimited?** I am using C#.

Currently, I am using following code.

```
        StreamReader stream = null;
        if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
        {
            if (FileUpload1.FileName.EndsWith("txt") )
            {
                string filename = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/files"), Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + ".txt");
                FileUpload1.PostedFile.SaveAs(filename);
                Session["UploadedFileName"] = filename;
                stream = new StreamReader(FileUpload1.PostedFile.InputStream);
            }
            else
            {
                lblMessage.Text = "File format not supported. Please use a tab delimited .txt file.";
                pnlMessage.Visible = true;
                return;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            lblMessage.Text = "You must select a file to upload.";
            pnlMessage.Visible = true;
            return;
        }
```

Comment: I'm not sure that's possible. If you find no tabs in the file, perhaps that would indicate that the file is not what you're expecting, but maybe it means there's just one column per row. If you find multiple tabs on each line, how do you know whether or not it's really in the format required? Now if you say you're expecting _n_ columns with no more than _x_ characters in each column, then you'd have something that you could check.

Comment: As @MichaelTodd has mentioned, there's no true way to know. The best you could hope for is to make a wrapper class for what you're expecting and parse the file, value by value.

Comment: If you were to require a comma-separated file a .csv extension, would you be able to check if it is indeed comma-separated?

Answer (score 0):

The server control
Can only upload one file at a time
Upload multiple files are not supported